# Embedded arcs staying embedded after squaring.

Tags: general-topology, geometry, plane-curves

Let $a\colon [0,1] \to D^2 = \{z \in \mathbb{C}\colon |z| \leq 1 \}$ be a continuous map with $|a(0)| = |a(1)|$ and further assume that $a$ is an embedded - so $a$ is an embedded arc.  Let $f\colon D \to D$ given by $f(z) = z^2$.

Under what conditions is $f \circ a$ still injective?  It seems to me that a necessary and sufficient condition is that $a$ only intersect at most one of each pair radial arcs between $0$ and the unit circle that are identified by $f$, but it is unclear to me how to prove this.

Comment: If we let $a:X \to D$ be an injective mapping, the question can be resolved by directly considering the definition of injectivity of $f \circ a$. Can you take it from there? (As a hint, the proposed condition is sufficient but not necessary.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider $f \circ a \colon [0, 1] \to D^{2}.$ Then, $f \circ a$ is **not** injective if and only if there exist distinct $x, y \in [0, 1]$ such that
$$(f \circ a)(x) = (f \circ a)(y).$$ Note that
$$(f \circ a)(x) = f(a(x)) = a(x)^{2},$$ and similarly
$$(f \circ a)(y) = a(y)^{2}.$$ So, we have
$$a(x)^{2}  = a(y)^{2}.$$ Since $x \neq y$ and $a$ is injective, we have $a(x) \neq a(y).$ So, it follows that
$$a(x)  = -a(y).$$

So, $f \circ a$ is not injective if and only if there exist distinct $x, y \in [0, 1]$ such that $a(x) = -a(y).$ Therefore, $f \circ a$ **is** injective if and only if there do not exist distinct $x, y \in [0, 1]$ such that $a(x) = -a(y).$